# Function: what to use other than .append() to insert a list into another list in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a hard time putting together a function that works like this (inserting x into y):

```
insertfunc(['John', 14], [['Damian', 43], ['Gita', 65]], 0)
# y = [['John', 14], ['Damian', 43], ['Gita', 65]] < -- if z = 0

insertfunc(['John', 14], [['Damian', 43], ['Gita', 65]], 1)
# y = [['Damian', 43], ['Gita', 65] , ['John', 14]] < -- if z = 1
```

Here is my code (I really have no idea where to go from here):

```
def insertfunc(x, y, z):
    x = []
    y = [ [] ]
    z = 0 or 1

    if z == 0:
          x.append(y) # .append() only allows the list in the parentheses to 
 maintain its square brackets... How can I get all of them to keep it?

    else:
        for i in range(len(y)):
            y.insert(i, y)

    return y
```

Comment: it looks like you want `.extend()`, `lst= ['a','b']`, 
`lst.append(['c','e']) -> ['a', 'b', ['c','e']]`,
`lst.extend(['c','e']) -> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']`

Comment: Why are you assigning to `x`, `y`, and `z` at the start of your function? That overwrites the values that were passed into the function. BTW, `z = 0 or 1` sets `z` to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `+` operator to combine lists too:

```
if z == 0:
    y = [x] + y
else:
    y = y + [x]
```

But the append and insert functions *should* have worked for you:

```
if z == 0:
   y.insert(0, x)
else:
   y.append(x)
```

I don't fully understand what you mean by ".append() only allows the list in the parentheses to maintain its square brackets", but it looks like you're calling it incorrectly:

```
x.append(y)
```

This is trying to append the list `y` to the list `x`, when the `insert()` function would have been a better fit for what you're trying to do. I'm going to assume the output of this call was something like this:

```
['John', 14, [['Damian', 43], ['Gita', 65]]]
```

... and that's why it looked to you like only one of the lists was able to "maintain its square brackets." This is because you've appended the list `y` to the end of the list `x` - that's inserting a whole list (of lists) inside `x` at the end, right alongside `'John'` and `14`. Your datatypes haven't changed, you just inserted the wrong one into the other, so you ended up with three nested levels of lists.

Comment: Ah, you got there just before me!  I was also going to add that in this situation you could reduce the function to a single line with a ternary: `return [x] + y if z == 0 else y + [x]`

Comment: You could, but I'm not a big fan of ternary operators. I generally find them harder to read than just listing the conditions on separate lines. I like whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function

```
def insertfunc(x, y, z):
    if (z == 0) :
        return [x]+y
    elif(z == 1):
        return y+[x]
```